# How to extract data from a dataframe which corresponds to a profile?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

I have a dataframe, which is a spatial data with coordinates and multiple other entries.

```
df.columns=['longitude','latitude',....,'data']
```

If I have the coordinates of a line profile,

```
profile=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
```

and consider the profile have a custom width (5 km),
How to extract the subset of the data rows in the dataframe which falls inside this profile?

(Is there a particular function for this in geopandas or shapely?)

Comment: Are you loking for something like `contains()`, implemented in [gepandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html) or [shaply](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.contains)?

Comment: yeah!If I could make a rectangle polygon with the custom breadth, which replace the line, I think maybe this will work.

Answer (score 1):

- use a number of UK cities to demonstrate
- randomly select 4 cities `dfp.sample(4)` generate a **shapely** line string from these co-ordinates
- add a buffer of 10km to this line (which means it becomes a polygon).  Note use of CRS systems to be able to define distance in km
- do a spatial join of buffered line to all cities
- graph shows that additional cities have been identified (not just 4 cities on the line)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import requests, json
import plotly.express as px

# source some points and polygons
# fmt: off
dfp = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0]
dfp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    dfp,
    geometry=dfp.loc[:,["Longitude","Latitude"]].apply(shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1),
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)
# fmt: on

# construct a LineString from 4 random points
line = shapely.geometry.LineString(
    dfp.sample(4).loc[:, ["Longitude", "Latitude"]].values
)
# add a buffer to LineString (hence becomes a polygon)
DISTANCE = 10 ** 4  # 10km
line = (
    gpd.GeoSeries([line], crs="EPSG:4326")
    .to_crs(dfp.estimate_utm_crs())
    .buffer(DISTANCE)
    .to_crs("EPSG:4326")
)
df_near = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=line).sjoin(dfp)

px.scatter_mapbox(df_near, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude").update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 4,
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": json.loads(line.to_json()),
                "below": "traces",
                "type": "fill",
                "color": "lightgrey",
            }
        ],
    }
)
```

[image]

#Edit removed the unwanted space which give the error message

Answer (score 0):

I edited Rob's solution for my particular problem by adapting some important from it.

```
cata=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

def cata_extraction(cata,polygon):
    
    bool_q1=[]
    
    for i in range(0,len(cata)):
        point = Point(cata.lon[i],cata.lat[i])
        bool_q1.append(polygon.contains(point))
    
    bool_q1=pd.DataFrame(bool_q1)
    ind_bool_q1=pd.DataFrame(np.where(bool_q1==False))  #ind_bool.iloc[0]
    cata_out = cata.drop(cata.index[ind_bool_q1.iloc[0]])
    return cata_out ;


x1=76;y1=29;x2=82;y2=36
width=10 #in km
# line=LineString([Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2)]).wkt
line=LineString([Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2)])

# add a buffer to LineString (hence becomes a polygon)
DISTANCE = width ** 4  # width km
line = (
    gpd.GeoSeries([line], crs="EPSG:4326")
    .to_crs(dfp.estimate_utm_crs())
    .buffer(DISTANCE)
    .to_crs("EPSG:4326")
)

line_hull=line.convex_hull
# line.convex_hull.coords

cata_out=cata_extraction(cata,line_hull)
```

But somehow it is giving an error when I use a higher value like `width=100`.
Error I am getting is the following:
`ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value`.
Any idea?